# Listing the unique categories of a variable containing a specific word

Tags: stata

I would like to list all the unique values of a variable `Company_Name` containing the word "credit".

Is there a way to do this in Stata?

Comment: DIstinct is a much better word for your meaning than unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with a toy *string* variable:

```
clear
input str25 v1
"National Credit Bank"
"Regional Exchange Bureau"
"Credit Astra Limited"
"Cleveland Bank"
"National Credit Bank"
end

generate v2 = strmatch(lower(v1), "*credit*")

levelsof v1 if v2, local(wanted)
`"Credit Astra Limited"' `"National Credit Bank"'
```

If the variable is *numeric* just `decode` it first:

```
input long v3
3
4
2
1
3
end

label values v3 v3
label define v3 1 "Cleveland Bank", modify
label define v3 2 "Credit Astra Limited", modify
label define v3 3 "National Credit Bank", modify
label define v3 4 "Regional Exchange Bureau", modify

decode v3, generate(v4)
```